# splitting a string after certain character and saving it to an array in java

Tags: split, substring, indexof

I have the following string array.

```
String [] MakesModels = {"BMW-Series 1, Series2", "Citroen-C1,C2", "Audi-A1, A2"};
```

From this string I am in need of taking out the "makes" being `(BMW, Citroen and Audi)` to populate them in a `JCombobox`. So far i have done this.

```
for (String m : MakesModels){
    MakeCMB.setModel(default new comboBoxModel(m.substring(0, (m.indexOf("-")))));
}
```

Once again from this string I am in need of taking out the Models being `(Series 1, Series 2, etc...)` to populate them in a second `JComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
for (String m : MakesModels){
            //Get maker 
           m.substring(0, (m.indexOf("-")));
           //Get models - array
          m.substring(m.indexOf("-")+1).split(",");            

        }
```